# Shared folder with access control and logging

Tags: windows, access-control

At work we are 20 people who access a folder thats shared on a computer running Windows 2003 Server Enterprise.

We've been facing issues with people playing pranks by deleting some files every now and then and I have been asked to setup some sort of an access control mechanism which also includes logging. Trouble is i am totally new to this :l

There are three types of sub-folders within the shared folder:
1) RW to all
2) RW to a subset of the users and RO to the rest (teams working on reports need RW, while those referring to the reports need RO)
3) RW to individual users, RO to others (folders where people store personal stuff)

All access to the folder needs to be logged.

Can this be achieved without using any third party software?

I've tried google, but haven't managed to dig up something similar. This is a bit like ~ on linux, where the user gets to set rwx permissions, with logging...only that I am trying to do it on Windows.

Any help is greatly appreciated.